# Why does Meta Stackexchange appear under the Technology tab on the network page?

Tags: discussion, meta, stackexchange.com

I figure it's because it used to be meta.stack**overflow**.

[image: screen shot of the issue]

I don't think it's a problem, but I *am* curious.

Comment: I don't think Meta SE would fit under any of the other categories...  [*Especially* not Professional](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It discusses [issues in the software that supports all the Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

> Support, feature requests, or bug reports for the core Stack Exchange engine that powers all Stack Exchange websites

I've found the following bug in the Stack Exchange software which affects all Stack Exchange sites... would be on-topic here.

Comment: Good answer, I suppose I've mostly looked for and asked more social/community questions there.